# Understanding this definition of a relation on an ideal

Tags: set-theory, ideals, relations, cardinals

In Kunen's Set Theory, he gives a definition of $R_{\mathcal{I}}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal.

> If $R$ is a relation on $B$ and $\mathcal{I}$ is an ideal with dual filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $A$ and $f,g\in B^A$, then $f R_{\mathcal{I}}g$ iff $f R_{\mathcal{F}}g$ iff $\{a\in A: f(a) R f(b)\} \in \mathcal{F}.$

How do I interpret this definition?  The third expression in the equivalence chain contains $b$ free, but the notation $f R_{\mathcal{I}}g$ does not have a $b$.  Furthermore, the third expression does not contain $g$ at all.  What is the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more context I can’t be positive, but I’m reasonably sure that the last expression should be $\{a\in A:f(a)\mathrel{R}g(a)\}\in\mathscr{F}$. Intuitively, $f\mathrel{R_\mathscr{I}}g$ iff $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are related for a ‘large’ set of $a\in A$. Here members of $\mathscr{I}$ are to be thought of as small subsets of $A$ and their complements as large subsets.

Comment: thats what i was thinking, that potentially it was a typo in the text, although it shows up twice more with the notation in the given definition (the $b$ and no $g$).  I don't even know what this definition is suppose to be called so I don't know what look up

Comment: @BENG: It looks like preparation for ultrapowers or something similar.